# How to append to a file an already existing output?

Tags: python, file, append

So I am using a raspberry pi and sense hat. I'm trying to write code to find the temperature, humidity, and pressure every minute, then save it to a file. I've already written code that will find temp, pressure, and humidity every minute.

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import time, sleep
while True:
  sleep(1 - time() % 1) # 
  sense = SenseHat()
  # Take readings from all three sensors
  t = pressure = sense.get_pressure()
  print(pressure)
  p = temp = sense.get_temperature()
  print(temp)
  h = humidity = sense.get_humidity()
  print(humidity)

  # Round the values to one decimal place
  t = round(t, 1)
  p = round(p, 1)
  h = round(h, 1)

  # Create the message
  # str() converts the value to a string so it can be concatenated
  message = "Temperature: " + str(t) + " Pressure: " + str(p) + " Humidity: " + str(h)

  # Display the scrolling message
  sense.show_message(message, scroll_speed=0.05)

from time import time, sleep
while True:
    sleep(60 - time() % 60)
```

Now I need to save the output information to a file. I know that I can append whatever I want to say by using:

```
f = open("sensedata.txt", "a")
f.write("temp, pressure, humidity")
f.close()

#open and read the file after the appending:
f = open("sensedata.text", "r")
print(f.read())
```

But I need to be able to append data that I've already found aka temp pressure and humidity. I have tried appending
`" t \n, h \n, p \n,"` because I've already defined that `t = temp` `p = pressure` and `h = humidity` but it literally came up on the file as  `t \n, h \n, p \n`. I don' know what I should do.

Comment: where is your code? that have " t \n, h \n, p \n,"

Comment: You're writing the literal string `temp, pressure, humidity`, not the values of the variables.

Comment: another note: why `t = pressure = sense.get_pressure()`?? `pressure = sense.get_pressure()` or `t = sense.get_pressure()` was ok, you dont need to save pressure value in two variable, save it only in one

Answer (score 0):

use it:

```
f = open("sensedata.txt", "a")
f.write(f" {t} \n, {h} \n, {p} \n,")
f.close()
```

to get more info about work with string in python [click here](https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

string concating in python:

1-simple:

```
a="welcome"
b="stackoverflow"
print(a  +   " to "   +   b)
```

output is:
`welcome to stackoverflow`

note: in this method `a` and `b` must be `str`

2-f string

```
print(f'{a} to {b}')
```

3-format

```
print(('{} to {}').format(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Separating out the reading and the writing into different function is a good idea.

To append to the file you want to open it with mode `a` and to create it for the first time you open it with mode `w`.

It is often helpful with sensor reading to have the results as a CSV file for later processing.

Reading the sensor every minute is difficult when the scrolling of the text on the display may take different lengths of time. It may be easier to look if the minute value has changed on the clock.

Here is an example of what that might look like:

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

from sense_hat import SenseHat


CSV_LOG = Path('/tmp/sensor_readings.csv')
sense = SenseHat()


def read_sensor():
    return {
        "Time": datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
        "Pressure": round(sense.get_pressure(), 1),
        "Temperature": round(sense.get_temperature(), 1),
        "Humidity": round(sense.get_humidity(), 1),
    }


def show_reading(sensor_reading):
    message = str(sensor_reading)
    print(message)
    sense.show_message(message, scroll_speed=0.05)


def write_reading(sensor_reading):
    first_write = not CSV_LOG.exists()
    open_mode = 'w' if first_write else 'a'
    with CSV_LOG.open(open_mode) as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ["Time", "Temperature", "Pressure", "Humidity"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        if first_write:
            writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow(sensor_reading)


def main():
    last_reading_minute = -1
    while True:
        if datetime.now().minute != last_reading_minute:
            last_reading_minute = datetime.now().minute
            sensor_values = read_sensor()
            show_reading(sensor_values)
            write_reading(sensor_values)
        sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My test printing out the following:

```
{'Time': '2021-11-07T18:07:29.445745', 'Pressure': 63, 'Temperature': 33, 'Humidity': 45}
{'Time': '2021-11-07T18:08:29.455906', 'Pressure': 72, 'Temperature': 25, 'Humidity': 37}
{'Time': '2021-11-07T18:09:29.458768', 'Pressure': 45, 'Temperature': 24, 'Humidity': 71}
```

And wrote the following to `/tmp/sensor_readings.csv`:

```
Time,Temperature,Pressure,Humidity
2021-11-07T18:07:29.445745,33,63,45
2021-11-07T18:08:29.455906,25,72,37
2021-11-07T18:09:29.458768,24,45,71
```

Note: Rather than have the endless `while` loop in your program, it may be more efficient to create a [crontab](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/using_linux.html#scheduling-tasks-with-cron) or [systemd timer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198444/run-script-every-30-min-with-systemd) to run the python script at the correct time interval.

Comment: What emulator are you using that this code worked on?  We are using https://trinket.io/sense-hat and when I put this in it didn't work. Also, I do not plan to use a scrolling text display because I will not be able to see the display, it will be in the sky. I just need to find the information and have it saved to a file so when we recover the raspberry pi and sense hat we can see the temp, pressure, and humidity.

Comment: I had made the assumption that you had the actual hardware. Apologies. The `csv` module isn't available on trinket emulator. However, it does appear to be available on the ISS according to https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/code-for-your-astro-pi-mission-space-lab-experiment/3 . It seems like the emulator is aimed at Mission Zero which looks to be more restrictive.

Comment: Actually using the sense hat and raspberry pi, this should work if I run it on thonny right? Or what did you run it on?

Comment: Yes, I am running it on a Raspberry Pi. Looking at the Astro Pi documentation they are using Python 3.7 so I have moved the Sense Hat on to a RPi with that version of Python. My original answer had an f-string that is not supported in 3.7 so I have updated the answer to remove that. The code in the current answer has been run on a Raspberry Pi running Python 3.7 and a Sense Hat connected.